# c++ winapi SendInput unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent

I have the following code, compiled using Visual C++ compiler

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;

    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    INPUT in;
    in.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    in.mi = {
        screenWidth / 2,
        screenHeight / 2,
        0,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,
        0,
        NULL
    };

    SendInput(1, &in, sizeof(in));

    GetCursorPos(&p);
    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My display is 1920x1080. From the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx), it seems that if I use relative movement (which I am in this case), dx and dy should be the difference in pixels.

When I ran this code, I placed my cursor at the top-left corner of my display and I was expecting it to end up at the center, however it ended up at (1243, 699), way past the center. Couldn't figure out why.

The exact reading of the 2 cout are

```
0 0
1243 699
```

Comment: DPI virtualization is the reason

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you elaborate on this please? I'm a real newbie and I couldn't find any documentation for the effect of DPI virtualization on mouse events.

Comment: Just don't hard-code 960 and 540.  Call GetSystemMetrics() to get the size of the screen, divide by 2 to get the mouse in the center.  Now you've written dpiAware code that works on any machine, regardless of the size of the screen and whether DPI virtualization is on or off.

Comment: @HansPassant I queried GetSystemMetrics for screen width and height and they are indeed 1920x1080. I changed my code to width/2 and height/2 yet no luck, its still ending up at 1243,699

Comment: @ShawnLi: Your coordinates are being inflated by ~1.29%. Looks like DPI scaling to me. Read about DPI effects on the mouse in MSDN's [Mouse Movement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153550.aspx) and [DPI and Device-Independant Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173.aspx) documentations. For instance, a DPI setting of 120 uses DIPs that are 1.25 pixels in size. Hmm... Do you have a DPI-aware manifest in your app, or use `SetProcessDpiAware()`/`SetProcessDpiAwareness()`?  If not, try adding that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added SetProcessDPIAware() to the top of my main function. Still no luck.

Comment: All seems rather implausible. How about a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag and convert the points to mouse coordinates (`0` to `0xFFFF`) to set the mouse coordinates. Otherwise the x/y coordinates are regarded as relative positions.

> [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> If `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is specified, dx and dy contain
>   normalized absolute coordinates between `0` and `65,535`. The event
>   procedure maps these coordinates onto the display surface. Coordinate
>   (`0`,`0`) maps onto the upper-left corner of the display surface,
>   (`65535`,`65535`) maps onto the lower-right corner.
>
> If the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` value is not specified, `dx` and `dy` specify
>   relative motions from when the last mouse event was generated (the
>   last reported position). Positive values mean the mouse moved right
>   (or down); negative values mean the mouse moved left (or up).
>
> **Relative mouse motion is subject to the settings for mouse speed and
>   acceleration level**. An end user sets these values using the Mouse
>   application in Control Panel. An application obtains and sets these
>   values with the `SystemParametersInfo` function...

Use an array for the second parameter in `SendInput`

```
int main() 
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;

    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    cout << screenWidth << " " << screenHeight << endl;

    p.x = screenWidth / 2;
    p.y = screenHeight / 2;

    INPUT in[1] = { 0 };
    in[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    in[0].mi.dx = (p.x * 0xFFFF) / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1);
    in[0].mi.dy = (p.y * 0xFFFF) / (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1);
    in[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

    SendInput(1, in, sizeof(INPUT));

    GetCursorPos(&p);
    cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, using the absolute flag definitely give me expected results. However, is there any reasons why the relative mouse movements are not working as intended?

Comment: *I was expecting it to end up at the center* You don't seem to understand the documentation, or you don't understand the meaning of "relative" and "relative motion". `screenWidth / 2` will not end up at the center in relative motion, unless the initial position was at the 0, 0. It's clearly indicated in your code that you intend to use exact screen coordinates.

Comment: As you can see from my output. My cursor is at 0,0 before SendInput

Comment: See the documentation on relative position *"Relative mouse motion is subject to the settings for mouse speed and acceleration level"* ...

Comment: Ah, yes, the mouse speed and acceleration level was the cause